# Send message to group members via facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to login to my own facebook account on a server via the api and send a message from the server to all members of a specific private group, in which I am also member?

Comment: No, you can not send private messages via API. If you want to communicate with group members - then make a post into the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to send user to user messages with the API.